# problem opening searchview only zero position

Tags: java

```
Good day, I'm making a mistake where the search view always opens the zero position
```

Continuously opens zero position when filtering.

how can I solve this problem

***Kitalar Adaptor***

```
 public class KitalarAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter {


        ArrayList<KitalarVersiyon> items;

        public KitalarAdaptor(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<KitalarVersiyon> items) {


            super(context,layout);
            this.items=items;

        }

        public void update(ArrayList<KitalarVersiyon> result){

            items=new ArrayList<>();
            items.addAll(result);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        public  class ViewHolder{
            TextView textview;
            ImageView ımageView;
            TextView yüzölçümü;
            TextView nufus;
            TextView ülkesayısı;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
          View row;
          row=convertView;
          ViewHolder viewHolder;
          if (row==null){
              row=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.kitalricinozzellayout,parent,false);
              viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
              viewHolder.ımageView=row.findViewById(R.id.kitalarimage);
              viewHolder.textview=row.findViewById(R.id.kitalartext);

              viewHolder.yüzölçümü=row.findViewById(R.id.yüzölçümü);
              viewHolder.nufus=row.findViewById(R.id.nufus);
              viewHolder.ülkesayısı=row.findViewById(R.id.ülkesayisi);


    row.setTag(viewHolder);
          }
          else{

              viewHolder=(ViewHolder) row.getTag();

          }

          viewHolder.ımageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).kitalarimage);
            viewHolder.textview.setText(items.get(position).kitalarname);
            viewHolder.yüzölçümü.setText(items.get(position).yüzölçümüaaaa);
            viewHolder.nufus.setText(items.get(position).nufus);
            viewHolder.ülkesayısı.setText(items.get(position).ülkesayısı);

            return  row;
        }
    }
```

***KitalarVersiyon***

```
 public class KitalarVersiyon {

        String kitalarname;
        int kitalarimage;
        String yüzölçümüaaaa;
        String nufus;
        String ülkesayısı;
        public KitalarVersiyon(String kitalarname, int kitalarimage, String yüzölçümüaaaa, String nufus, String ülkesayısı) {
            this.kitalarname = kitalarname;
            this.kitalarimage = kitalarimage;
            this.yüzölçümüaaaa = yüzölçümüaaaa;
            this.nufus = nufus;
            this.ülkesayısı = ülkesayısı;
        }



    }

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu,menu);
            MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.searchmenu);
            final SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {


                    ArrayList<KitalarVersiyon> result=new ArrayList<>();
                    for (KitalarVersiyon x:items){

                        if (x.kitalarname.contains(s))
                            result.add(x);


                    }

                    ((KitalarAdaptor)listView.getAdapter()).update(result);


                    return false;
                }
            });


            return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }








 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {





                if (position==0){

                    Intent ıntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),Afrikakitasi2.class);
                    startActivity(ıntent);
                }




            }
        });
```